# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `log_visitor`

Tags: mysql, magento

I have installed Magento 1.9.1 But now following error message appears when try enter to magento, before this error works correctly my site but now not know whats happend i hope can help me thanks!.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO `log_visitor` (`session_id`, `first_visit_at`, `last_visit_at`, `last_url_id`, `store_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Trace:
#0 /home/chikatrendy/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/chikatrendy/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/chikatrendy/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/chikatrendy/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#4 /home/chikatrendy/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#5 /home/chikatrendy/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `lo...', Array)
#6 /home/chikatrendy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(453): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('log_visitor', Array)
#7 /home/chikatrendy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#8 /home/chikatrendy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php(168): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#9 /home/chikatrendy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Log_Model_Visitor->initByRequest(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#10 /home/chikatrendy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor), 'initByRequest', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /home/chikatrendy/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#12 /home/chikatrendy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(527): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#13 /home/chikatrendy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php(64): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#14 /home/chikatrendy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->preDispatch()
#15 /home/chikatrendy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#16 /home/chikatrendy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#17 /home/chikatrendy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#18 /home/chikatrendy/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /home/chikatrendy/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}
```

I have read a lot of threads and also used Google but could not find a solution. I am a beginner and the shop should work tomorrow again :-( I very much appreciate your help!

Thanks a lot for your help & best regards

Comment: It says it on the first line. You are trying to add a log entry but you can't add another record with 0 as the primary key. When you have a look at the log_visitor table, what's the primary key column? Does it have an auto increment setting?

Comment: Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
0
16bb0ffe9618bbdf83f5bf96eea61a27
2015-02-10 21:49:19
2015-02-10 21:49:20
0
1

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything, sorry. Add the table description of the log_visitor table to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the below line to

```
SET foreign_key_checks=0;
```

at the beginning of the .sql backup file and the below line at the end.

```
SET foreign_key_checks=1;
```

Hope it works.